# JupyterLab "File Save Error" "Out of Memory"

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I have opened a text file ~208MB in JupyterLab.

I deleted a few lines and then tried to save it.

I get the message: 'File Save Error for foobar.txt - Out of Memory'

How do I get around this and save my edited text file please?

Thanks in advance.